# JPA and toplink create-table on if they don't already exist?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, persistence.xml

Looks like jpa is something which makes me ask a lot of questions.

Having added this

```
<property name="toplink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
```

my JPA application always creates tables when running, which results in exceptions in case the tables already exist. I would like JPA to check if the tables already exist and if not create them, however I could not find a value for the property above which does this.

So if I just turn it off, is there a way to tell JPA manually at some point to create all the tables?

Update here's the exception I get

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'tags' already exists
Error Code: 1050
Call: CREATE TABLE tags (ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(255), OCCURRENCE INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

MySQLSyntaxErrorException?! Now that's wrong for sure

Comment: So did you end up just ignoring the printed exceptions or did you do a work around.

Comment: Look at the time when I asked this question.. one way to work around this would probably be to just extend the build script to drop the tables before building / deploying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/JPA/essentials/toplink-jpa-extensions.html#Java2DBSchemaGen  toplink does not have an option to update exiting tables, I'm not sure if I would trust it to do the right thing anyway.
You could configure toplink to generate a sql script that you then would have to execute manually to create all tables. The filenames and location can be configured like this:

```
<property name="toplink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
<property name="toplink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="sql-script"/>
<property name="toplink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="createDDL.sql"/>
<property name="toplink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="dropDDL.sql"/>
<property name="toplink.application-location" value="/tmp"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would like [my] JPA [provider] to check if the tables already exist and if not create them, however I could not find a value for the property above which does this.

Weird, according to the TopLink Essentials documentation about the `toplink.ddl-generation` extension, `create-table` should leave existing table unchanged:

> #### [TopLink JPA Extensions for Schema Generation](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/JPA/essentials/toplink-jpa-extensions.html#Java2DBSchemaGen)
>
> Specify what Data Descriptor Language
>   (DDL) generation action you want for
>   your JPA entities. To specify the DDL
>   generation target, see
>   [`toplink.ddl-generation.output-mode`](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/jpa/resources/toplink-jpa-extensions.html#toplink.ddl-generation.output-mode).
>
> **Valid values:** `oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider`
>
> - `none` - do not generate DDL; no
>     schema is generated.
> - `create-tables` - create DDL for
>     non-existent tables; leave existing
>     tables unchanged (see also
>     [`toplink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name`](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/jpa/resources/toplink-jpa-extensions.html#toplink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name)).
> - `drop-and-create-tables` - create DDL for all tables; drop all existing
>     tables (see also
>     [`toplink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name`](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/jpa/resources/toplink-jpa-extensions.html#toplink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name)
>     and
>     [`toplink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name`](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/jpa/resources/toplink-jpa-extensions.html#toplink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name)).
>
> If you are using persistence outside
>   the EJB container and would like to
>   create the DDL files without creating
>   tables, additionally define a Java
>   system property `INTERACT_WITH_DB` and
>   set its value to `false`.

Comment: I'm not using EJBs here (and not even an application server) I just noticed some exceptions when running it and with the db already existing, but thx for pointing this out

Comment: @Nils: I'm not sure to understand your comment. The above applies when using TopLink Essentials as JPA provider in a Java SE environment too and I think you misread the last sentence of the documentation. This answer strictly covers your question here (which was not about updating existing tables).

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase (http://www.liquibase.org) is good at this.  It takes some time to get fully used to it, but I think it's worth the effort.

The Liquibase-way is independent of which JPA persistence provider you use.  Actually, it's even database agnostic.